# Typescript: Spread types may only be created from object types

Tags: typescript

```
function foo<T extends object>(t: T): T {

  return {
    ...t // Error: [ts] Spread types may only be created from object types.
  }
}
```

I am aware that there are issues on github, but I can't figure out what is fixed and what is not and they have 2695 open issues. So I am posting here. I am using latest Typescript 2.9.2.

Should the above code not work? And how can I fix it if possible?

Comment: Looks like it fails to cast `t` to `object` correctly. Try `function foo<T extends object>(t: T): T {
    return { ...(t as object) } as T;
}`, it's weird, but works

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This is fixed in TypeScript Version 3.2. See [Release Notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-spread-expressions-in-object-literals).

---

Looks like spread with a generic type isn't supported yet, but there is a GitHub issue about it: [Microsoft/TypeScript#10727](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727).

For now you can either use [type assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions) like [@Jevgeni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4088001/jevgeni) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189388/typescript-spread-types-may-only-be-created-from-object-types#comment89360927_51189388):

```
function foo<T extends object>(t: T): T {
  return { ...(t as object) } as T;
}
```

or you can use `Object.assign` which has proper type definitions.

```
function foo<T extends object>(t: T): T {
  return Object.assign({}, t);
}
```

Comment: You know what, as `tslint` say: `[tslint] Use the object spread operator instead.` :'(

Comment: @CliteTailor So change the lint rule if you don't like. Linters are supposed to help you establish certain rules, not stop you from writing things you want to write.

Comment: Typescript 4.2 and still facing the same. I cast `...(t as Record<string, unknown>)` to pass the lint as suggested by the linter @@

Comment: TS 4.9 same error. Spread operators and generic types combined. A call to `Object.assign` works for my code.

Answer (score 42):

You can use `Record<string, unknown>` or an interface like the below examples:

```
goodsArray.map(good => {
  return {
    id: good.payload.doc.id,
    ...(good.payload.doc.data() as Record<string, unknown>)
  };
});
```

or

```
goodsArray.map(good => {
  return {
    id: good.payload.doc.id,
    ...good.payload.doc.data() as Goods // 'Goods' is my interface name
  };
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Version 3.2 of Typescript fixed this. The two PRs that improve handling of spread and rest parameters are:

- [Generic object rest variables and parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28312)
- [Generic spread expressions in object literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234)

You can try it out now using `npm install typescript@3.2`.

With 3.2 your code works as is.

Version 3.2 has been released on November 29th, 2018, you can read more about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/11/29/announcing-typescript-3-2/#object-spread-on-generic-types).

Comment: And it's released on the last day of November: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/11/29/announcing-typescript-3-2/

Comment: I still get this error with version 4.5, so this is likely not fixed

Comment: @Danielo515 What is your exact code? Maybe the scenario is a bit different ? I'd be curious to see

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, if interested, I have similar issue with this for example: `let someObject: { [key: string]: number };` can't spread `...someObject`

Answer (score 6):

If you are still getting this error post version 3.2 then you probably have a type error 'upstream' resulting in an object being `unknown` instead of an actual object. For instance if you have the spread expression `{ ...getData() }` but your `getData` function has a compile error you may see this error.

So check for any compiler errors in your browser console because the final error may be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with `react-hook-form`

I just did this:

```
{...(register('fieldName') as unknown as Record<any, unknown>)}
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer may help to fix the same problem while using angular and firestoe.

`return { id: item.payload.doc.id,
...item.payload.doc.data()}
as Employee`

this on will throw he same error. for fixing you have to change like this one.

`return { id: item.payload.doc.id,
...item.payload.doc.data() as Employee }`