# (TS) Spread types may only be created from object types

Tags: typescript

I have been implementing Aurelia-DragNDrop. However, its written in Javascript as are the docs and examples and I am working in Typescript.

In the course of implementing the examples I have come across the above error. I therefore researched the spread operator on SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189388/typescript-spread-types-may-only-be-created-from-object-types).
It recommended using "...(xxx as object)" however my variable is already typed as an array from what I can gather. Other answers were not clear or React orientated - I even tried the Typescript playground with no success.

The code:

```
@computedFrom('items', 'intention')
get patchedItems() {
    const { items, intention } = this;
    if (!intention) return items;

    let patched = _.reject(items, { id: intention.id });
    const item = _.find(this.items, { id: intention.id });

    if (item) {
        // always show current moving item on top
        patched.push({ ...item, x: intention.x, y: intention.y });
    }

    return patched;
}
```

Items have been declared at the top of the class as:

```
@bindable items = [
    { id: 'a', name: 'A', x: 20, y: 20 },
    { id: 'b', name: 'B', x: 50, y: 200 },
    { id: 'c', name: 'C', x: 200, y: 100 }
];
```

There was also chatter about the fact that this was going to be addressed in 3 etc.. I am on Typescript 3.4.

Here is a picture of the error:

[image: Spread Types can only be created from object types]

How can I write this so the compiler doesnt complain?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem isn't the spread operator but that you're using `underscore`'s method wrong, therefore getting something unexpected. For [`reject`](https://underscorejs.org/#reject), you have to pass a function not an object, like this:

```
const patched = _.reject(items, (i) => i.id === intention.id)
```

Then the same for `find` or you can use [`findWhere`](https://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) instead:

```
const item = _.find(this.items, (i) => i.id === intention.id)
// or
const item = _.findWhere(items, { id: itention.id })
```