# How to deploy a Typescript, NodeJS and Express app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku

I wanted to provide a howto on this as I couldn't find any complete information.  I thought that this seemed most appropriate in Stackoverflow documentation. However it has been sunsetted *-) - [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) (*).

Instead I will write this as a StackOverflow Q&A.

How to deploy a Typescript, NodeJS and Express app to Heroku

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a project (https://gitlab.com/OehmSmith_Examples/herokumovies) that includes a README describing what needs to be done and I will reproduce that here.  As a good StackOverflow practice I will also provide a copy of all the code at the bottom of this post.

## Tutorial - Deploy Typescript NodeJS Express app to Heroku

This tutorial will work from https://amenallah.com/node-js-typescript-jest-express-starter/ as the base app.  I have no affiliation with that site or the author.  I chose it as it is simple and works.  It is also an  example of good OO Typescript code.

### Install typescript

Most tutorials or even the official documentation in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html say to install typescript globally:

```
 > npm install -g typescript
```

**Heroku doesn't have a global install of typescript so it needs to be kept locally.**  The example project does just this:

```
 > npm i -D nodemon rimraf typescript ts-node ts-jest jest @types/jest @types/node
```

### @types/node

In the case you have pinned your `@types/node` at an older version you will see something like this error:

```
~/AppData/Roaming/nvm/v11.15.0/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:41:6 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.

41 type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:170:11
    170 interface IteratorResult<T> { }
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'IteratorResult' was also declared here.

node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:170:11 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.

170 interface IteratorResult<T> { }
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

~/AppData/Roaming/nvm/v11.15.0/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:41:6
    41 type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'IteratorResult' was also declared here.


Found 2 errors.
```

From [TypeScript: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331779/typescript-duplicate-identifier-iteratorresult).  And as per that you need to update your version of `@types/node`.  This was a problem I struck as I was working with older code and wanted to include this discussion of it.

### Update port for cloud service

Change the `index.ts` to be the following instead since the original code hard-coded port 5000:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server started on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
});
```

To allow for this I have added the PORT to the `npm scripts`, including adding a `start:dev` so you can run it like Heroku does from the compiled typescript.

```
    "start:dev": "PORT=5000 node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "PORT=5000 nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts --watch src",
```

Or it can be set in a .env file:

```
PORT=5000
```

### NPM dependencies

Heroku will NOT install dev dependencies (neither will any other cloud provider).  Therefore you need to move some dependencies to the main block.  For example, a `NestJS` application has these as Dev Dependencies and they need to be moved:

```
 @nestjs/cli
```

### Dummy data

I added this constructor to the `MoviesApi.ts`:

```
constructor() {
    // setup some dummy data
    movies.push({
        name: 'Pirates of the caribbean',
        rating: 8.5
    })
    movies.push({
        name: 'Star Wars: A new hope',
        rating: 8.7
    })
}
```

### Heroku

Now deploy to Heroku

1. Setup an account if you don't already have one and create an app on Heroku
2. In your terminal:

   ```
   heroku login
   heroku create moviesheroku // this needs to be unique
   ```
3. You may need to add the returned git url as a remote (check with `git remote -v`):

   ```
   git remote add heroku <git url>
   ```
4. Lookup or search for buildpacks with (the next step already specifies those I use):

   - Lookup at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#officially-supported-buildpacks
   - Search with:

     `heroku buildpacks:search typescript`
5. Add buildpacks:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add zidizei/typescript
   heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
   ```
6. Confirm buildpacks:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks
   ```
7. Commit to your local repository

   ```
   git init  // if not already done
   git add --all
   git ci -m "Initial commit.  Test project all setup and should be ready to 'serve' but not yet ready to deploy to heroku"
   ```
8. Run with

   ```
   npm dev # OR
   npm run start:dev # It depends on your npm scripts
   ```
9. Test with postman or similar or run this from the command-line:

   ```
   curl http://localhost:5000/movies
   ```
10. Test that it transpiles with `npm run build`
11. Update the npm scripts so that after installation (`npm install`) on Heroku, it will build it before attempting to `npm run start`

    ```
    "postinstall": "npm run build"  # Depends on your npm scripts
    ```
12. Commit to local repository:

    ```
    git add --all
    git ci -m "Now it should deploy, build and run on heroku"
    ```
13. Deploy to heroku.  It should build and start up.

    ```
    git push heroku master
    ```
14. Test (assuming the app you `heroku create`d is `moviesheroku` - adjust accordingly)

    ```
    curl https://moviesheroku.herokuapp.com/movies
    ```

### Variations

#### Procfile

I haven't specified a `Procfile` telling Heroku anything about the app.  Fortunately it creates its own defaults by determining that this is a `node + npm` app.  However you can explicitly define this and will need to perform this action if you have multiple apps or similar.  You could add a Procfile to contain (this is the default):

```
web: npm start
```

#### Node and NPM version

Heroku also defaults to using one of the most recent versions of these.  You could explicitly set the versions at the top-level in the `package.json` file like:

```
 "engines": {
     "node": "10.x",
     "npm": "6.x"
 },
```

Although if you don't specify a `npm` version then Heroku will use a sensible default for the version of node.

### Concluding thoughts

I had this going in only a couple hours.  The main issues I needed to work out is that typescript has to be local, not global.  And the buildpacks.  The PORT is an issue also though every cloud provider requires the use of `process.env.PORT` so this was obvious to me.

Azure was a nightmare and took days, but that was mainly because the workplace I was at insisted on using Windows servers.  Long story and I won't go in to it.

AWS was so convoluted.  I didn't get the instance I had working after trying for a day.  however I do need to try again.  The app I was trying used the https://tsed.io/ library.  Simple Node / Typescript / Express apps should work out quite easily.

(*) - the sunsetting of documentation was a little bit surprising though given it happened over 2 years ago I guess it wasn't something I used.  And I always thought that the Q&A was the easiest place for documentation.

## Code

`.gitignore`

```
    node_modules
    dist
    coverage
```

`.jest.config.js`

```
    module.exports = {
        preset: 'ts-jest',
        testEnvironment: 'node'
    };
```

`package.json`

```
    {
      "name": "movies",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Example from https://amenallah.com/node-js-typescript-jest-express-starter/ but then modify and / or show steps for how to deploy this Typescript NodeJS Express RESTful app to Heroku.",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
        "postinstall": "npm run build",
        "start": "node dist/index.js",
        "start:dev": "PORT=5000 node dist/index.js",
        "dev": "PORT=5000 nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts --watch src",
        "test": "jest --watch",
        "coverage": "jest --coverage"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.25",
        "@types/node": "^13.1.2",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
        "ts-jest": "^24.2.0",
        "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
        "typescript": "^3.7.4"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1"
      }
    }
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "*": [
            "node_modules/",
          ],
          "typings/*": [
            "src/typings/*"
          ]
        },
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "src/test/**/*.spec.ts"
      ]
    }
```

`src/api/MoviesApi.ts`

```
    import IResource from "typings/IResource";

    let movies: object[] = []

    export default class MoviesApi implements IResource {
        constructor() {
            // setup some dummy data
            movies.push({
                name: 'Pirates of the caribbean',
                rating: 8.5
            })
            movies.push({
                name: 'Star Wars: A new hope',
                rating: 8.7
            })
        }

        create(data: any): any {
            movies.push(data)
            return data
        }

        findMany(): any[] {
            return movies;
        }
    }
```

`src/test/api/Movies.spec.ts`

```
    import IResource from '../typings/IResource'
    import MoviesApi from '../api/MoviesApi'

    const moviesApi: IResource = new MoviesApi()

    describe('Movies API', () => {
        it('should create a new movie', () => {
            const movieData: object = {
                name: 'Pirates of the caribbean',
                rating: 8.5
            };

            const movie: object = moviesApi.create(movieData);

            expect(movie).toEqual(movieData)
        })
    });
```

`src/typings/IResource/index.d.ts`

```
    export default interface IResource {
        create(data: any): any
        findMany(): any[]
    }
```

`src/index.ts`

```
    import * as express from 'express'
    import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'

    import MoviesApi from './api/MoviesApi'

    const app = express();
    const moviesApi = new MoviesApi();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.post('/movies', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        res.json(moviesApi.create(req.body))
    });

    app.get('/movies', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        res.json(moviesApi.findMany())
    });

    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log(`server started on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
    });
```

Comment: You probably saved my entire week, thank you so much!