# I'm getting this error on build using tsc

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I'm getting this error on the build using tsc

Can someone check this, please?

> ```
> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:75:11 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.
>
> 75 interface IteratorResult<T> { }
> ```

I'm using latest typescript and @types/node

My package json configuration

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-statsd": "^0.3.0",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "hashids": "^1.2.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.1",
    "nyc": "^13.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.7",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "strong-error-handler": "^2.3.0",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.41",
    "@types/node": "12.12.31",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
```

someone can help me, please?

Any update to do?

Comment: Did you try `npm update --save-dev @types/node`? Found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331779/typescript-duplicate-identifier-iteratorresult

Comment: you need to figure out a better title. It needs to have enough information so that when it appears in SO search results, people can decide whether it relates to their own problem.

Comment: You should update the title as @Inigo suggested. Maybe change it to:  `Using build tsc getting error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to reinstall your packages. This should solve your problem.

```sh
sudo rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json

sudo npm cache clean --force

sudo npm install -D @types/node 

sudo npm i --unsafe-perm
```

Ps: You may get some type errors after all these fresh installs. This is something you will have to fix by declaring or correcting or installing "@types/". You have reinstalled your modules and some type errors appeared.Find the the code where the types are not compatible and fix it. This way you will understand reading typescript errors and fixing types. And your code will be type safe, whole point of using Typescript.

Comment: it works, but now I'm getting this error
Overload 1 of 2, '(associatedClassGetter: ModelClassGetter, foreignKey?: string | undefined): Function', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ foreignKey: { name: string; unique: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(associatedClassGetter: ModelClassGetter, options?: BelongsToOptions | undefined): Function', gave the following error.
   
 

55   @BelongsTo(() => Company, {
56     foreignKey: { name: "companyId", unique: "email_active_unique" }

Comment: @CarlosVieira This error is fine. This is something you will have to fix by declaring or correcting or installing "@types/". you have reinstalled your modules and some type errors appeared.Find the the code where the types are not compatible and fix it. This way you will understand reading typescript errors and fixing types.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try npm install package.json (if you are not using visual code terminal you might need to add the correct path to your file!)