# How to resolve this error: "Error: node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:X:X - error NG1010: Value"

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Whenever I run my angular project file with the help of `ng serve -o` in command prompt, it gives an error.

Here's the error I observed:

[image]

> Error: node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:5501:22 - error NG1010:
> Value
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:50302, open your browser on http://localhost:50302/ **
>
> × Failed to compile.

I reinstalled both angular and node. I installed node packages several time with the help of `NPM install`. I create new angular project and paste my source folder of previous project in new project file.

Angular cli version :

[image: Image of version]

Comment: Some code would be useful. A compilation error indicates some issue with your code.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331779/typescript-duplicate-identifier-iteratorresult) looks like someone had a problem like you (sorry if not help)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps

1. Delete the **node_modules** folder from your project directory.
2. Open the command prompt or terminal and run **npm install** to install
   all the required packages for your project.
3. After the packages are installed, try running the project again with
   the command **ng serve -o**.