# Typescript: spread operator not working unless using keyword "as"

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript but understand the keyword `as` is type assertion.  I have a Promise that is supported to return a type of an interface `CodeWork`.

I had 2 constant that I was combining in the shape of that interface like this:

```
  const part1 = Object.entries(grabData)[1][1] ?? null;
  const part2 = Object.entries(grabData)[1][1] ?? null;

  const allData = {...part1, ...part2};
  return allData;
```

but my code editor shows an editor of the spread operators saying "Spread types may only be created from object types".  When debugging, the data is the correct shape so I assume it's solely a type issue.

When I change it to:

```
  const part1 = Object.entries(grabData)[1][1] ?? null;
  const part2 = Object.entries(grabData)[1][1] ?? null;

  const allData = {...part1 as CodeWork, ...part2 as CodeWork};
  return allData;
```

that doesn't show the error in the editor anymore.  Even though the data is the same shape, I still need to use type assertion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Spread types may only be created from object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189388/typescript-spread-types-may-only-be-created-from-object-types)