# How to group and concat values by keys in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try like a maniac to do some kind of a merge / sort by key on an array of object.
Don't know why but I cannot figure how to do that.

My app is in Ionic / Angular.

Here is what I have :

```
[
  {
      "2021": {
          "a": "aText"
      }
  },
  {
      "2021": {
          "b": "bText"
      }
  },
  {
      "2020": {
          "z": "zText"
      }
  },
  {
      "2020": {
          "y": "yText"
      }
  },
  {
      "2020": {
          "x": "xText"
      }
  }
]
```

My goal is to get this :

```
[
  {
      "2021": { "a": "aText", "b": "bText" }
  },
  {
      "2020": { "z": "zText", "y": "yText", "x": "xText" }
  }
]
```

In other words, I'd like to regroup by year and concat them.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do that ?

Comment: Instead of an array of objects why not use an object where the years are the keys? Probably easier to manage.

Comment: That was another option that I tryed but everything is dynamic and kinda screw my thinking...

Comment: You should add the code you've tried as a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: I've tryed so many possible ways that I don't even know what to show you. The result is always the same, I cannot manipulate the returned data and do a simple concat of them... Mind about to explode :)

Comment: Andy, your first comment made me think of something. You are right with the object with  years as keys. The problem when I do this is how do I check if the key is in the object multiple times (if so, I can do the concat). Don't know if I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a single object with years as keys then it's just a standard 'group by' with a nested loop to iterate the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of each object. If you do want your originally posted output (an array of individual objects) you can just [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the entires of the returned grouped object and convert each to an object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const input = [
  { 2021: { a: 'aText' } },
  { 2021: { b: 'bText' } },
  { 2020: { z: 'zText' } },
  { 2020: { y: 'yText' } },
  { 2020: { x: 'xText' } },
];

const grouped_object = input.reduce(
  (a, o) => (Object.entries(o).forEach(([y, o]) => (a[y] = { ...(a[y] ?? {}), ...o })), a),
  {}
);

// if you just want a single object with years as keys
console.log(grouped_object);

const grouped_array = Object.entries(grouped_object)
  .map(([year, data]) => ({[year]: data}));

// the output from your question
console.log(grouped_array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or refactored to use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const input = [
  { 2021: { a: 'aText' } },
  { 2021: { b: 'bText' } },
  { 2020: { z: 'zText' } },
  { 2020: { y: 'yText' } },
  { 2020: { x: 'xText' } },
];

const grouped_object = {};
for (const obj of input) {
  for (const [year, data] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    grouped_object[year] = Object.assign(grouped_object[year] ?? {}, data);
  }
}

// if you just want a single object with years as keys
console.log(grouped_object);

// or avoiding computed properties
const grouped_array = Object.entries(grouped_object)
  .map(([year, data]) => (o={}, o[year]=data, o));

// the output from your question
console.log(grouped_array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Pilchard but I got an error when I try your first proposition : "Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2019' or later."

Comment: Replaced the `Object.fromEntries()` call with an object literal declaration using computed properties. Sounds like you're compiling to an older spec in which case use the `Object.assign` example above as spread syntax probably isn't supported either.

Comment: Pilchard, I've replace in my tsconfig.json "lib": ["es2018", "dom"] TO "lib": ["es2019", "dom"] and the problem is gone PLUS I now have the result that I wanted. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use an object to group by year. This is an example that uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the array to produce that object.

```js
const data=[{2021:{a:"aText"}},{2021:{b:"bText"}},{2020:{z:"zText"}},{2020:{y:"yText"}},{2020:{x:"xText"}}];

const out = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {

  // Get the key and value from the object that in
  // the current iteration
  const [ [ key, value ] ] = Object.entries(obj);

  // If the key doesn't exist on the accumulator (the initial
  // object that we passed into the `reduce`) create an empty object
  acc[key] = acc[key] || {};

  // Update the value of that object property with
  // the value of the object
  acc[key] = { ...acc[key], ...value };

  // Return the updated object for the next iteration
  return acc;

// Here's the initial object that
// acts as the accumulator through all the iterations
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Or using an array to hold the information for each year:

```js
const data=[{2021:{a:"aText"}},{2021:{b:"bText"}},{2020:{z:"zText"}},{2020:{y:"yText"}},{2020:{x:"xText"}}];

const out = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {

  const [ [ key, value ] ] = Object.entries(obj);

  // Use an array instead of an object
  acc[key] = acc[key] || [];

  // Push the first element of the Object.values
  // into the array
  acc[key] = [ ...acc[key], Object.values(value)[0] ];

  return acc;

}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries)
- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy but I got this error message : "Spread types may only be created from object types" on the "...value". Any idea ?

Comment: [Sounds like a TS warning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189388/typescript-spread-types-may-only-be-created-from-object-types). The JS works fine as you can see in the example.

Comment: Andy, your were right, that was a warning. After changing in tsconfig.json "lib": ["es2018", "dom"] TO "lib": ["es2019", "dom"] everything worked (hope it won't break the rest of my app).  Thanks for your help. Prichard's code did the trick but yours helped me a lot too. I can't give you more than my respect for your help.